# axios call node js express route with parameter

Tags: node.js, express

```
const response = await axios(`http://localhost:9000/model/${id}`);
```

on my routes folder model.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
// can't get here


});
```

on app.js

```
var modelRouter = require('./routes/model');
app.use('/model', modelRouter);
```

I'm very new to node JS and express, might be missing something but can't figure out what.

so far i only get

> GET /model/341rtertwert 404

**Update**

For whoever steps upon this question, there is no correct answer. I tried Sweet Chilliy Pilly answer and it did not work, maybe because I'm using module routes in separate files. However I changed back to the way i had it and tried to access the route through url with some random parameter and it worked. After it worked aswell using axios. I did restart node js several times. In other words, I have no idea why it decided to work now. But it's solved.

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing, and getting the 404. Is the code above working? Can you post an answer with working code? Appreciate any more info...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 404 at this route `/model/341rtertwert` because you have defined your route to be `/:id`. In your situation, your router is looking for a route called /model/341rtertwert.

What you likely need to implement is paramed routes: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

If you changed your route to be

```
router.get('/model/:id', function (req, res, next) {
// can't get here


});
```

then this should work.

Comment: i think this would work if i had the route on the app.js. However i tried your approach again, and then when i changed back it worked when i tried to reach the url through the browser and now works with axios. I don't even know what happened

Comment: @Jackal Either way we got to the solution! im happy to have helped :)

Comment: You're missing that the router is `app.use('/model', router)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you but he does state that in his post, do you think i should add that to my answer as well?

Comment: You suggesting `router.get('/model/:id', ...)` is just wrong because `/model` is already specified when the router itself is registered.  So, your  answer is just wrong.  Your route would be for `/model/model/someID`, not what the OP asked for.  That's what I'm saying.

Comment: My way is fine if he declares the router like so `app.use(modelRouter);` I assumed it would still work regardless